# Implicit and explicit components with same inputs

Tags: openmdao

How can you define implicit and explicit outputs in the same component considering they have the same inputs ?

I tried to do this with implicit component, like this.

```
class Dis(ImplicitComponent):

def setup(self):
    self.add_input('a')
    self.add_input('b')
    self.add_input('c')
    self.add_output('z')

    self.add_output('y1')
    self.add_output('y2')
    self.add_output('y3')

    self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')

def apply_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, residuals):

    residuals['z'] = (1 - outputs['z']) / (inputs['a']) ** 0.5 * inputs['b'] - inputs['c']

def solve_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs):

    outputs['y1'] = (1 - outputs['z']) / (inputs['a']) ** 0.5 * inputs['b']
    outputs['y2'] = inputs['a'] * (0.01 * outputs['z'] + 1)
    outputs['y3'] = inputs['b'] * (outputs['y2'] / inputs['a'])
```

So, in the same discipline I need `z` to vary to satisfy the residual equation and I need it to compute `y1`, `y2` and `y3` for the rest of my system.

However, OpenMDAO considered all of the outputs as implicit ones, consequently the DirectSolver I used later in my system had a "Singular matrix" issue. To fix that, I created a group composed of two components: one explicit for my variables that directly depends on inputs and another implicit one, which uses the same inputs, like this.

```
class Dis1(ImplicitComponent):

def setup(self):

    self.add_input('a')
    self.add_input('b')
    self.add_input('c')
    self.add_output('z')

    self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')

def apply_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, residuals):

    residuals['z'] = (1 - inputs['z']) / (inputs['a']) ** 0.5 * inputs['b'] - inputs['c']

class Dis2(ExplicitComponent):
def setup(self):

    self.add_input('a')
    self.add_input('b')
    self.add_input('c')

    self.add_input('z')

    self.add_output('y1')
    self.add_output('y2')
    self.add_output('y3')

    self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')

def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

    outputs['y1'] = (1 - inputs['z']) / (inputs['a']) ** 0.5 * inputs['b']

    outputs['y2'] = inputs['a'] * (0.01 * inputs['z'] + 1)
    outputs['y3'] = inputs['b'] * (outputs['y2'] / inputs['a'])

class Top(Group):
def setup(self):

    self.add_subsystem('compz', Dis1())
    self.add_subsystem('comp_exp', Dis2(), promotes_outputs=['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])

    self.connect('compz.z', 'comp_exp.z')

    self.set_order(['compz', 'comp_ex'])
```

Is there a way to put them in a single component ? I mean a component which is able to compute residuals and give explicit outputs as well.

Comment: Please provide some code what you try so far and a working example

Comment: if your equations are simple enough to post here, a code sample of what you tried would make it much easier to give you a complete answer

Comment: Sorry, I edited my request.